# Where to declare long ng-style attributes Angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Say I have the following snippet in an Angular project:

```
<div ng-app="ExampleApp" ng-controller="ExampleController as controller" ng-init="">
    <div ng-style="styleRules={'background-color':'blue', 'width':'100px', 'height':'100px'}"></div>
</div>
```

If "styleRules" contains a dozen or more CSS rules, should I still keep the entire JSON object in-line, or should it be moved to another file? If it should be moved, to where should I move it?

Comment: Put them in the controller `ExampleController`. But since your styles are strings why not just add them to your `.css` file, whats the point of using `ng-style`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's primarily static as the example you provided, I'd recommend moving it to a `$scope.styleRules` variable in your script and referencing it in `ng-style="styleRules"`.

### Update

Actually if it's static, just put the rules in the `style` attribute.  While not required, you only need to include the dynamic rules in `ng-style`.

Comment: Actually, if it's static, put the styles in a CSS stylesheet and use a `class` attribute.